# Insert an image into database

Tags: sql, sql-server

In image column, image data is displaying in weird way.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBJgF.jpg)

I run this query.

```
UPDATE dbo.Book
SET Image = (
    SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'E:\dot net practice\practice 4\images\Pride and prejudice.jpg', Single_Blob) AS img
)
WHERE id = 3
```

The query runs without any error, but the output is not what I was expecting.

Comment: This is not mysql syntax, so I removed the tag [tag:mysql].

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: What is the data type of the `Image` column?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I just made the table from asp.net core using migration in which I used the property this 'public string? Image { get; set; }'. I am practicing this project from youtube. He didn't show how he add data to database

Comment: I am expecting that it will show all data to the web application. It shows all data except the image. The database about books includes id, name,auther_name, genre, and image. All the data is showing but image is not displaying.

Comment: Well why is it a `string`, why aren't you storing it as a `byte[]` array (a `varbinary(max)` column)?